# Rails loopback/redirection issue in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am new to Rails, Currently I am working on Rails application which is back-end and Angular as a front end. I am getting an issue like in my production server when I go to backend(rails) URL, it redirects me to root URL of application and return 502 for every rails request. I have checked CORS but not any issue in it. Same code is working find in my local development enviornment.

Can anyone help me to find this issue?

Comment: did you check which error are you getting in console ?

Comment: Please check your ploduction.log

Comment: Yes, I have checked logs but there is not any log entry. When I checked tail -f shared/log/puma.stdout.log this logs then it returns workers booted error.